# C# read line by line from PHP POST response

Tags: c#, php

I want to parse every line from PHP response.
I tried:

**PHP:**

```
echo "Line 1\n";
echo "Line 2\n";
echo "Line 3\n";
```

**C#**

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
client.addLine(responseString);
```

I get every echo in each line but I can't use it to process it separately.

when I do

**C#**

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadLine();
do
{
    client.addLine(responseString);
    responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadLine();
}   while (responseString != null);
```

I get only the first line and each next loop returns null.
How can I get every line separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of `\n`, windows uses `\r\n` as line terminator. Try replacing `\n`'s with `\r\n`.And do not create stream reader for each iteration

```
var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
do
{
    client.addLine(reader.ReadLine());

}  while (!reader.EndOfStream);
```

Comment: Yeah you're right with "\r\n" + this code works great and is even shorter than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you control php output, it might be easier to use JSON to communicate between php and C# if possible, as generating and parsing JSON is much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for advice but I prefer PHP as I need it only for connecting to database. Everything else I do in C#. Although I may reconsider it later.